# PHP/Javascript/AJAX file upload via drag and drop. Files get converted to strings

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a problem while uploading files using a drop area. It seems that files get converted to strings when they arrive at the backend. I'm adding the file objects to a new array because I want the users to be able to remove unwanted files before they submit the form.

The form looks like this:

```
<form action="" class="dropzone" id="image_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="upload-input">
        <label for="delivery_address" id="delivery_address_label">Delivery address</label>
        <input type="text" name="delivery_address" id="delivery_address" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="" id="drop-area">
        <p>Upload multiple files with the file dialog or by dragging and dropping images onto the dashed
           region
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="upload-input">
        <input class="btn btn-info w-100" type="submit" id="btnUpload" value="Send" />
    </div>

</form>
```

Javascript:

```
let dropArea = document.getElementById("drop-area");

let fileList = [];

['dragenter', 'dragover', 'dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
    dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, preventDefaults, false)
})

function preventDefaults(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
}

dropArea.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false)

function handleDrop(e) {
    let dt = e.dataTransfer;
    let files = dt.files;

    handleFiles(files);
}

function handleFiles(files) {
    files = [...files];
    files.forEach(addFiles);
}

function addFiles(file) {

    fileList.push(file);
}

btnUpload.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const form = document.getElementById("image_upload");
    const formData = new FormData(form);

    console.log(fileList);

    formData.append("fileList", fileList);

    xhr.open("POST", "add.php");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        document.getElementById("phpResponse").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    };

    xhr.send(formData);
});
```

And in the PHP file I'm just var dumping $_FILES for now to see what's going through:

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

Which returns

> array(0) { }

var_dump($_POST) returns:

> array(3) { ["delivery_type"]=> string(14) "Latvijas pasts" ["delivery_address"]=> string(6) "qweeqe" ["fileList"]=> string(27) "[object File],[object File]" }

I can't find where the problem is. The form is set to enctype="multipart/form-data". Before sending the form I console.log the fileList variable and it looks like the files are still files:

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append: _“[value] can be a USVString or Blob (including subclasses such as File). If none of these are specified the value is converted to a string.”_ - your `fileList` is a mere array, so the string conversion occurs, and the actual File instances turn into `[object File]`. You need to loop over your file list, and append the individual `File` instances you have there to your FormData instance one by one.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, I have to loop through every instance of `File` in the fileList array and append each `File` to FormData individually.

This part:

```
formData.append("fileList", fileList);;
```

Becomes:

```
for (let i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
    formData.append("fileList[]", fileList[i]);
}
```

And on the backend I can loop through every file:

```
foreach($_FILES['fileList']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){
    echo $_FILES['fileList']['name'][$key] . "<br />";
}
```